# How to allow only authorised useres to view website pages using express, cookie parser, JWT and mongoose

Tags: express, mongoose, cookies, routes, jwt

I am making a website that is supposed to only allow logged-in users to view some pages and those users are divided into 2 categories students and admin and both of them can't view the same pages. My problem is I don't know how to display the restrcitedAuth object to authenticate users and create a cookie while they are in the website in my main component :

Main app.js :
`

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const responseRoutes = require('./routes/responses.routes');
const examRoutes = require('./routes/exams.routes');
const createRoutes = require('./routes/create.routes');
const examIdRoutes = require('./routes/exams.id.routes');
const studentRoutes = require('./routes/students.routes');
const allStudentRoutes = require('./routes/all.student.routes');
const userRoutes = require('./routes/user.routes');
const userExamRoutes = require('./routes/user.exams.routes');
const errRoutes = require('./routes/404.routes');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth.routes');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');


//express app
const app = express();

//connect to mongoDB
const dbURI ='mongodb+srv://AdminUser:rjmfal2023@cluster0.1k6cgl9.mongodb.net/CSIA?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
mongoose.connect(dbURI, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
.then((result) => app.listen(3000)) 
.then(()=> {
    console.log("Mongodb is connected"); // 
})
.catch(()=>{
    console.log("failed to connect")
})
.catch((err) => console.log(err))

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');// middlewear
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended:true}));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser()); 


app.use(authRoutes);
app.use(responseRoutes);  // NEEDS FIXING ************************** (error in data fetching)
app.use(examRoutes);
app.use(createRoutes);
app.use(examIdRoutes);
app.use(studentRoutes);
app.use(allStudentRoutes);
app.use(userRoutes);
app.use(userExamRoutes);
app.use(errRoutes);
```

`

requireAuth middlewear object i created :

`

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const requireAuth = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.cookies.jwt;

    // Check if the token exists
    if (!token) {
        console.error('No token found in request');
        res.redirect('/inicio-sesion-usuario');
        return;
    }

    // Verify the JSON web token
    jwt.verify(token, 'secret', (err, decodedToken) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Invalid token:', err.message);
            res.redirect('/inicio-sesion-usuario');
            return;
        }

        // User is authenticated, proceed to next middleware or route handler
        console.log('User authenticated:', decodedToken.userId);
        next();
    });
};

module.exports = { requireAuth };
```

`

auth.routes.js:
`

```
const express = require('express');
const authController = require('../controllers/authController');

const router = express.Router();


router.get('/inicio-sesion-usuario', authController.user_get);

router.post('/inicio-sesion-usuario', authController.user_post);

module.exports = router;
```

`

authController.js:
`

```
const Student = require('../Models/students');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');


const createToken =(id) =>{
    return jwt.sign({id},'secret', {
        expiresIn: 3 * 24 *60 *60
    })
}

//handle errors 
const handleErrors = (err) => {
    console.log(err.message, err.code);
    let errors = { name: '', lastname: '', user: '', password: '' };

    if (err.message === 'contraseña incorrecta') {
        errors.password = 'Contraseña es incorrecta';
    }

    if (err.message === 'usuario incorrecto') {
        errors.user = 'Usuario no existe';
    }

    return errors;
};

module.exports.user_get =(req,res) =>{
res.render('userLog');
};

module.exports.user_post = async (req,res) =>{
    const {user, password} = req.body;
    
  try{
    const student = await Student.login(user,password);
    const token = createToken(student._id);
  

    console.log('Sent response to client:', { student: student._id, role: student.role });

    res.cookie('jwt', token,  {httpOnly : true, maxAge : 1000*3*24*60*60});
    
    res.status(200).json({ student: student._id, role: student.role });

  }
  catch(err){
    const errors = handleErrors(err);
    res.status(400).json({ errors });
  }
};
```

`

students.js schema :
`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const nameValidator = (value) => {
    return /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/.test(value);
};


const lastnameValidator = (value) => {
    return /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/.test(value);
};

const Schema = mongoose.Schema; //constructor function

const studentSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required : [true, "Ingresar un nombre"],
        validate: [nameValidator, 'Nombre solo tiene que tener letras']
    },
    lastname: {
        type: String,
        required : [true, "ingresar un appellido"],
        validate: [lastnameValidator, 'Apellido solo tiene que tener letras']
    },
    user: {
        type: String,
        required : [true, "ingresar un usuario"],
        unique:true
    },
    role: {
        type: Number, // 1 admin /examenes // 0 student /userPage
        required : true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required : [true, "ingresar una contraseña"],
    },
    examScores: {
        type: [{ name: String, score: Number , timeMin : Number}],
        default: []
        // Array of exams with exam name and score and time take to do
    },
}, {timestamps : true}); // auto assigns time values


//fire function after student is saved in database (post saving after saving)
studentSchema.post('save', function(doc,next){
    console.log('new student was created and saved', doc);
    next();
});

//fire function before student is saved in database // installed bcrypt to hash password
studentSchema.pre('save', async function(next){
   const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
   this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
   next();
});

/*steps for hashing 
1. run password through hashing algorithm
2. hashing algorithm generates a longer that seems random string
3. generate a salt (string of characters separate from the pasword) to password before hash so its harder to decrypt
4. password + salt encrypted stored in database

*/

// static method to login user
studentSchema.statics.login = async function (user,password){
    const userone = await this.findOne({user});
    if (userone){
        const auth = await bcrypt.compare(password, userone.password);
        if(auth){
            return userone;
        }
        throw Error('contraseña incorrecta')
    }
    throw Error('usuario incorrecto')

}

const Students = mongoose.model('students', studentSchema);
module.exports = Students;
```

`

example of what one of my routes looks like that has to have the requireAuth object but it doesn't work:

```
const express = require('express');
const exams = require('../Models/exams');
const {requireAuth } = require('../middlewear/authMiddlewear');


const router = express.Router();
router.use(requireAuth);

router.get('/examenes',  (req,res) =>{
    exams.find().sort({createdAt: -1}) //sorts from newest to oldest
    .then((result) =>{
        res.render('AdminMain', {exams : result})
    })
    .catch((err) =>{
        console.log(err)
    })
    
}) 


module.exports = router;
```

[image]
This login page is supposed to appear before any route if user has not logged in and it exists in the database but it never shows ie tried many ways :

such as this :
`app.use(authRoutes); app.use(responseRoutes); app.use(examRoutes); app.use(createRoutes); app.use(examIdRoutes); app.use(studentRoutes); app.use(allStudentRoutes); app.use(userRoutes); app.use(userExamRoutes); app.use(errRoutes);`

and this :
`app.use('/examenes', requireAuth, examRoutes.getExamenes); app.use('/examenes/create', requireAuth, examRoutes.createExamen); app.use('/examenes/:id', requireAuth, examRoutes.getExamenById); app.use('/examenes/:id/update', requireAuth, examRoutes.updateExamen); app.use('/examenes/:id/delete', requireAuth, examRoutes.deleteExamen);`